# Not moving to right

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic3

[image]

I need to move the `+` button to the right side.But below code is not working.Can you tell me why?

**.scss**

```
 .plusButton {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 11;
        color: white;
        float: right;
    }
```

**.html**

```
<button ion-button clear class="plusButton"> <ion-icon name="add-circle"></ion-icon></button>
```

Comment: what about this: `.plusButton {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 11;
        color: white;
        top: 16px;
        right: 16px;
    }`?

Comment: Yes, it is working.But can you tell me how you decided it should be `right:16px`? Will it not an issue on `ipad` (i.e. larger device)? @sebaferreras

Comment: Ionic usually uses a padding of `16px` in the content (when you add the `padding` attribute to the content `<ion-content padding>...` so, I always use the same padding when I need to so something *outside* Ionic...

Comment: OK, Thanks. can you put that as an answer? @sebaferreras

Comment: Sure, just did that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
.plusButton { 
  position: absolute; 
  z-index: 11; 
  color:white; 
  top: 16px; 
  right: 16px; 
}
```

Please notice the `top` and `right` values. Ionic usually uses a padding of 16px in the content (when you add the `padding` attribute to the content `<ion-content padding>...` so, I always use the same padding when I need to do something **outside** Ionic.

Also please notice that if the button was inside of a `navbar`, I'd recommend using the `<ion-buttons end>...<ion-buttons>` container to place it on the right, but in this case seems like the button is not part of a `navbar`/`toolbar`, so I guess we can just fix it by using css.

Comment: Yes, You're right about the `navbar` use case.I'm not using `navbar` here.Thanks :)

Comment: Np, glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use **right** property to align element to rigth. And assign position **relative**  to which you want to set right alignment.

```
.plusButton {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 11;
    color: white;
    right: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with item-end property of ion-button

```
<button ion-button item-end>...</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't use `absolute` and `float` together, the `float` won't work because `absolute` is there.
You have many options to make it work, the better way I prefer is to use `margin` and `absolute`. please make sure the button is written after arrow in DOM, then you can use `margin-left` and `margin-top` to adjust the position of this button.

```
.plusButton {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 11;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-botton: 10px;
}
```

Of course you can use `right:0`as @Vijay Kumar B said but you have to define the parent `DIV` as `relative`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the value position to relative.

```
.plusButton {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 11;
    color: white;
    float: right;
}
```

https://fiddle.jshell.net/5wzptbpj/